# Computing the radical of the ideal $\langle x^3+y^2-1,y-1\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

**Question:** Compute ${\rm rad}(\langle x^3+y^2-1,y-1\rangle)$ in $\Bbb C[x,y]$.

Naming $J=\langle x^3+y^2-1,y-1\rangle$ I solved $y-1=0$ and $x^3+y^2-1=0$
which gives $$V(J)={(0,1)}.$$

So, $$I(V(J))=\langle x,y-1\rangle. $$ Is this correct?

Comment: I reckon that $\langle x^3+y^2-1,y-1\rangle=\langle x^3,y-1\rangle$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng I am new to Nullstellensatz algebra, can you demonstrate the steps you used?

Comment: @Borbious You have $x^3+y^2-1=x^3+(y+1)(y-1)$ and so on. No need of Nullstellensatz.

Comment: @ShiveringSoldier Indeed, but i want to learn this method for now. I think probably the part (If $V(J)=(0,1)$, then $I(V(J))=<x,y-1>$) is wrong

Comment: @borbious to be clear, your solution is correct

Comment: @BrianShin Oh, okay then, thanks for clarifying it.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Can you please make that an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method of solving the problem is sound, but a more naive approach is to note that
as $x^3+y^2-1=x^3+(y+1)(y-1)$ then $J=\left<x^3,y-1\right>$. Then it is plain that
$$\left<x,y-1\right>\supseteq J\supseteq\left<x,y-1\right>^3.$$
As $\left<x,y-1\right>$ is a maximal ideal, then taking radicals gives
$$\left<x,y-1\right>\supseteq\sqrt J\supseteq\left<x,y-1\right>$$
etc.

Answer (score 4):

Radical of an ideal equals the intersection of its minimal prime ideals. If $P$ is a minimal prime over $J$, then $y-1\in P$ and $x^3+y^2-1\in P$. Since $y^2-1=(y-1)(y+1)$ we get $x^3\in P$ hence $x\in P$. Since the ideal $(x,y-1)$ is prime we get that this is the only minimal prime over $J$, so $\sqrt J=(x,y-1)$.